# Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ValueError: Empty training data

Tags: r, deep-learning

I am trying to set up a deep learning model in R and received the error      message that no training data is available. Could someone please help?

clothing_reviews <- read.csv("C:/Users/Astrid/Documents/Master BWL/Data Mining mit R/R/Präsentation 2/Womens Clothing Reviews.csv") %>%
+   mutate(Liked = ifelse(Rating == 5, 1, 0),
+          text = paste("Title", "Review.Text"),
+          text = gsub("NA", "", text))

> glimpse(clothing_reviews)
>   Observations: 28,222
>   Variables: 13
>   $ X                              "0", "1,1080,34,,\"Love this dress!  it's sooo pretty.  i happened to fi...
>   $ Clothing.ID                    767, , , , 847, , , , 1077, , 1077, 1095, , ,  so i would say it's runni...
>   $ Age                            33, , , , 47, , , , 24, , 53, 39, , , , , , 50, , , 41, , , , , , , , , ...
>   $ Title                          , , , , Flattering shirt, , , , Flattering, , Dress looks like it's made...
>   $ Review.Text                    Absolutely wonderful - silky and sexy and comfortable, , , , This shirt ...
>   $ Rating                         4, , , , 5, , , , 5, , 3, 5, , , , , , 3, , , 5, , , , , , , , , , , , ,...
>   $ Recommended.IND                1, , , , 1, , , , 1, , 0, 1, , , , , , 1, , , 1, , , , , , , , , , , , ,...
>   $ Positive.Feedback.Count        0, , , , 6, , , , 0, , 14, 2, , , , , , 1, , , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , ...
>   $ Division.Name                  Initmates, , , , General, , , , General, , General, General Petite, , , ...
>   $ Department.Name                Intimate, , , , Tops, , , , Dresses, , Dresses, Dresses, , , , , , Dress...
>   $ Class.Name...................  Intimates;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;, , , , Blouses;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;, , , , Dr...
>   $ Liked                          0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...
>   $ text                           "Title Review.Text", "Title Review.Text", "Title Review.Text", "Title Re...
>
> clothing_reviews %>%
>   +   ggplot(aes(x = factor(Liked), fill = Liked)) +
>   +   geom_bar(alpha = 0.8) + 
>   +   guides(fill = FALSE)
>
> reviews_total<-rbind(clothing_reviews$Liked,
>   +                      clothing_reviews$text)
>
> reviews_m<-as.matrix(reviews_total)
>   dimnames(reviews_m)<-NULL
>
> set.seed(123)
>   ind<-sample(2,nrow(reviews_m),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))
>   reviews_train<-reviews_m[ind==1,1]
>   reviews_test<-reviews_m[ind==2,1]
>   reviews_trainlabel<-as.numeric(reviews_m[ind==1,2])
>   reviews_testlabel<-as.numeric(reviews_m[ind==2,2])
>   Warning message:
>   NAs introduced by coercion
>
> maxlen<-100
>   max_words<-10000
>   tokenizer<-text_tokenizer(num_words=max_words)%>%
>   +   fit_text_tokenizer(reviews_train)
>   sequences<-texts_to_sequences(tokenizer, reviews_train)
>   word_index= tokenizer$word_index
>
> x_train<-pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=maxlen)
>   y_train<-as.array(reviews_trainlabel)
>
> batch_size <- 20
>   epochs <- 12
>
> model <- keras_model_sequential()%>%
>   +   layer_embedding(input_dim = max_words, output_dim = 100)%>%
>   +   layer_lstm(units = 16)%>%
>   +   layer_dense(1)%>%
>   +   layer_activation("sigmoid")%>% compile(
>   +     loss = "binary_crossentropy",
>   +     optimizer = "adam",
>   +     metrics = "accuracy"
>   +
>   +   )
>
> hist <- model %>%
>   +   fit(
>   +     x_train,
>   +     y_train,
>   +     batch_size = batch_size,
>   +     epochs = epochs,
>   +     validation_split = 0.3

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Empty training data.

Comment: Format your code and add more details including sample data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example